# TYPO3 TCA forms using AJAX for drop down lists

Tags: ajax, forms, list, typo3

In my TCA forms I have two drop down lists, List 1 called `Campus` and List 2 called `Department` . The `Department` list should change depending on the value selected in the `Campus` list. In other words, the `Department` list depends on the selected `Campus` item.

How do I achieve this in TYPO3 TCA forms? Normally in HTML, I would use AJAX, what should I use here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this question resolved ? I have tried with unique answer but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use markers in your "foreign_table_where"-string.
One of them is the ###REC_FIELD_[fieldname]### marker.

Example:

```
'campus' => array(
    'label' => 'campus',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select'
    )
    'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_campus',
),
'department' => array(
    'label' => 'department',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select'
    )
    'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_department',
    'foreign_table_where' => " AND tx_myext_domain_model_department.campus = '###REC_FIELD_campus###'"
)
```

Additionally you have to tell TCA that a change of your campus field requests an update.

In ext_tables.php:

```
$TCA['tx_myext_domain_model_example']['ctrl']['requestUpdate'] .= ',campus';
```