# TYPO3 6.2 TCA Backend Form - How to fill Select dynamically in this example

Tags: mysql, forms, list, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have 3 Entities:

1. Appointment
2. Doctor (extend fe_users)
3. Specialization

Dependencies:

- Each appointment has exactly one doctor
- Each doctor has at least one specialization
- Each appointment has at least one specialization - but it can't be
  one that its doctor doesn't have

My goal:

After a doctor is selected you can choose which specialization of the doctor will be used in order to categorize the appointment - but multiselect should also be possible.

**Edit:** I came up with this SQL to make it clearer what I want in my Select-Field:

```
SELECT 
    s.name
FROM 
    tx_appointments_domain_model_specialization s, 
    fe_users fe,
    tx_appointments_doctor_specialization_mm ds,
WHERE 
    fe.username = "###REC_FIELD_doctor###" 
    AND ds.uid_local = fe.uid
    AND s.uid = ds.uid_foreign;
```

So the part of my TCA of `Appointment` looks like this now:
It's pretty much all generated by the extension builder except the `'foreign_table_where'` in `doctor` which I found out somehow. But I can't wrap my head around how to set the specialization now.

```php
'doctor' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'doctor',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => 'fe_users',
        'foreign_table_where' => "AND FIND_IN_SET('1', fe_users.usergroup) ORDER BY fe_users.last_name ASC, fe_users.first_name ASC",
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 1,
    ),
),
'specialization' => array(
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'specialization',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_appointments_domain_model_specialization',
        'MM' => 'tx_appointments_appointment_specialization_mm',
        'size' => 10,
        'autoSizeMax' => 30,
        'maxitems' => 9999,
        'multiple' => 0,
        'wizards' => array(
            '_PADDING' => 1,
            '_VERTICAL' => 1,
            'edit' => array(
                'module' => array(
                    'name' => 'wizard_edit',
                ),
                'type' => 'popup',
                'title' => 'Edit',
                'icon' => 'edit2.gif',
                'popup_onlyOpenIfSelected' => 1,
                'JSopenParams' => 'height=350,width=580,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
            ),
            'add' => Array(
                'module' => array(
                    'name' => 'wizard_add',
                ),
                'type' => 'script',
                'title' => 'Create new',
                'icon' => 'add.gif',
                'params' => array(
                    'table' => 'tx_appointments_domain_model_appointment',
                    'pid' => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                    'setValue' => 'prepend'
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I know I could use something like `'foreign_table_where' => ..."###REC_FIELD_doctor###"...` but I have no idea how the whole SQL should look like to get only the doctor's specializations showing.

And I'll probably have to add something like this in ext_tables.php which I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17485906/4120196) answer similar to my problem:

```
$TCA['tx_appointments_domain_model_appointment']['ctrl']['requestUpdate'] .= ',doctor';
```

Comment: I don't think I have done something like this before, just wanted to say that if all other options fail, you can always just use the userfunc to fetch the correct values with PHP: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/User/Index.html

Comment: thank you, that's very helpful - I'll try it with that!